# Custom VBA function to return a unique values as string breaks in first iteration

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a function that returns a list of any unique Limit of Range (LOR) test results. They are indicated in the data by a "<" or ">". The following code keeps breaking where indicated. I have searched and can't seem to find a problem with my logic up until this point.... what happens after who knows

```
Public Function LORConc(Data As Range) As String

Dim LOR As Range
Dim cll As Range
Dim tmp As String
Dim tmpR As Range

For Each cll In Data
tmp = cll.Value
If InStr(1, tmp, Chr(62)) <> 0 Or InStr(1, tmp, Chr(60)) <> 0 Then
    If Not LOR Is Nothing Then
        Set LOR = Union(LOR, cll)
    Else
        LOR = cll ' breaks here, no vba error, just returns #value error to cell
    End If
End If
Next

LOR.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=tmpR, Unique:=True
tmp = ""
For Each cll In tmpR
    tmp = tmp & "," & cll.Value
Next

If tmp = "" Then
findConc = "No LOR"
Else
findConc = tmp
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Don't forget **Set**   :   `Else Set LOR = cll`

Comment: That said, you will have other issues after this fix.Seems you are using this function as UDF, you can't apply filtering inside UDF.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It is the first time I have made one so thanks for the heads up about filtering. I will look for another way.

Comment: btw I'm embarrassed about not picking up the lack of set on that line... DOH!  (forehead slap)